# Live Audio HLS stream fails to play

Tags: http-live-streaming, google-cast, receiver, google-cast-sdk

we are trying to play a HLS Live stream that is Audio-only.
It looks ok spec-wise and we're able to play it on all browsers and native player that we have, but it fails to play on Chromecast.

Url: http://rcavliveaudio.akamaized.net/hls/live/2006635/P-2QMTL0_MTL/playlist.m3u8

Content-Type: vnd.apple.mpegURL

*Steps to reproduce*
Force this content url and content type into the Chromecast player.

*Expected*
To hear audio playing like on any other player we try.

*Actual result*
There is no playback. The master playlist is fetched, the chunk playlist is fetched and the first chunks are fetched, but there is no playback. It stops after a few chunk.
The player is stuck in the "processing segment" phase, and it stops.

Comment: Relevant:  https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/148805250

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the Content type to audio/mp4 and set AAC to segment format mediaInfo.hlsSegmentFormat = cast.framework.messages.HlsSegmentFormat.AAC;

Comment: @MarcDesharnais can you please tell me where to put this or have an example? I just started with a custom receiver and have no clue where to put this.

Comment: @AnjaneeshRayapati Can you elaborate on this answer?  Where are you getting `mediaInfo`?  Using the reference code, there is only `mediaInfo` on the sender, but `cast.framework.messages.HlsSegmentFormat.AAC` is only defined on the receiver.  In my case, I set `mediaInfo.hlsSegmentFormat = 'ts_aac'` on my *sender* (using the string value, not the defined constant), and I was able to get my stream to work.  But, this seems wonky, and different than what you're suggesting here.

Answer (score 0):

Using Anjaneesh's comment, here's how I ended up solving this.  On the receiver's JavaScript:

```
  const instance = cast.framework.CastReceiverContext.getInstance();

  const options = new cast.framework.CastReceiverOptions();
  options.disableIdleTimeout = true;
  options.supportedCommands = cast.framework.messages.Command.ALL_BASIC_MEDIA;

  instance.start(options);

  const playerManager = instance.getPlayerManager();
  playerManager.setMessageInterceptor(cast.framework.messages.MessageType.LOAD, (req) => {
    req.media.hlsSegmentFormat = cast.framework.messages.HlsSegmentFormat.TS_AAC;
    req.media.streamType = cast.framework.messages.StreamType.LIVE;
    return req;
  });
```

The key is setting the message interceptor callback for the `LOAD` event/message.  There, you can override `hlsSegmentFormat` from the client.  In my case, I needed to indicate that my segments were in TS format.

I'm not entirely sure why this is necessary.  It isn't necessary when there is a video track... only when video is missing.